# json_encode($data) = NULL

Tags: php, json

Maybe you can help me. DB connection is ok (`Connected successfully`), the table name is correct (`course_details`), but `echo json_encode($data);` is `NULL`

```
<?php

   include "db.php";

   // Check connection
   if ($con->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
   echo "Connected successfully";

   $data=array();
   $q=mysqli_query($con,"'SET CHARACTER SET utf8' select * from 'course_details'");
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
      $data[]=$row;
   }


   echo json_encode($data); 
   $conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the output of `$data`

Comment: Your query is going to fail. You have two statements that aren't separated, and one is surrounded by single quotes but should not be. You can't run two statements in a query without using `mysqli_multi_query`. And tables need to be surrounded by backticks, not quotes. This is why `$data` is empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

firstly I would suggest wrapping the query in a try catch block

secondly as is mentioned in the comments above you have 2 queries in in the string.

```
try{
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `course_details`");
    $data = [];
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($data); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "It reached the catch block " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Your query will still fail because of the single quotes around the table. And since it would return null instead of throwing an exception, the OP should check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: @aynber whats the problem with wrapping the table name in single quotes?

Comment: It will be treated as a string instead of a table or column name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql